# Comparing the percentage obtained from 2 groups with different sample size

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to compare the increase in percentage of $X$ variable in 2000 and in 2012, so I calculated the percentage of the $X$ variable in 2000 and in 2012 and subtracted the difference. My question is if the sample size is different is it still correct to compare the percentage? For example:

| Variable X | Count in 2000 | Count in 2012 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 89 | 114 |
| B | 9 | 33 |
| Total sample size | 98 | 147 |

So is it correct to say that there is an increase in $A$ even though the sample size of 2012 is higher?
Can you please help  me to understand this?

Edits:
The 2 data sets are for 2 different cohorts, one before 2000 and other in 2012. So the numbers are different because it represents all the patients at those periods. So I'm comparing the change of the percentage by counting how many of $A$ at the variable $X$ in 2000 and divide it by the total amount of the variable $X$  and times it by 100 to get the percentage. The I do the same thing for $A$ in 2012 to get the percentage and then subtract the difference. Note: Variable $X$ is categorical variable (for example: $X$ = A,A,A,A,A,B,A,T,A,B).

```
% of A in 2000 = Counts of A in 2000/ total counts of variable X in 2000 (A +B)*100
% of A in 2012 = Counts of A in 2012/ total counts of variable X in 2012 (A +B)*100 (A +B)*100
```

My concern is the difference in percentage that I'm getting is related to real increase in $A$ in 2012 or it is just because of the data set in 2012 is larger? How can I correct for this difference? Can I do a proportion test to check if this increase is real? The null hypothesis for the proportion test would be:
Null= There is no increase in $A$
Alternative= There is an increase in $A$.
Is it correct to use the proportion test to check if the difference is real and not related to the differences in sample size?

Please,any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: No it's not ! Thereis obviously an increase in A. But what you can say is that there is a decrease in the realtive share of A, from 90% to 77.5% ..

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Hi, thank you very much for your reply. Sorry i meant an increase I'll change it. Can I do a proportion test to see if this increase is significant assuming that the null hypothesis is there should be no increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also seems appropriate to use `prop.test` in R, as below.
The proportion of A's in the two years are
about $0.978$ and $0.776,$ which are judged to be significantly
different proportions because the P-value is near $0.$

```
prop.test(c(89,114), c(91, 147))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(89, 114) out of c(91, 147)
X-squared = 16.798, df = 1, p-value = 4.158e-05
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1197452 0.2852783
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.9780220 0.7755102
```

This is essentially the same as a chi-squared test of
homogeneity of the $2\times 2$ table of counts with rows
for A and B and columns for 2000 and 2012. [On account
of the moderately large sample sizes, one might
omit the continuity correction, with parameter `cor=F`
in `prop.test` and in `chisq.test` on the $2 \times 2$
table mentioned just above.]

Comment: Thank you very much, its appreciated. By doing the proportion test, does this mean that if i get significant results means there is  a true difference that is not related to differences in the sample sizes of the both cohorts?

Comment: Because what i'm doing is that i'm subtracting the percentage of the amino acid before 2000 and the percentage after 2012. So if i find a difference lets say over 10 percent and i want to make sure that this is not related to the difference in sample size i can do binomial test in this case? and the binomial test means there is a true difference regardless the sample size?

Comment: The tests in my Answer compare proportions of counts. An analogy would be to say a coin with 89 heads and 9 tails in 98 tosses is more heavily weighted towards heads than a coin with 114 heads and 33 tails in 147 tosses. // In your study, why is there a larger sample size in 2012? Was that your choice. // Can't follow your account of the expt. Why do you think there may be more amino acid in 2012? And more in what? //  Your table suggests there were 235 randomly sampled experimental units. What are they and how selected? Hope you will add procedural section at the end of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the difference in the proportions

$$d = \frac{x_1}{n_1} - \frac{x_2}{n_2} = \frac{89}{98} - \frac{114}{147} \approx 0.133$$

and compute an estimate for the error of it by using the variance of a [binomial proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

$$Var[\hat{p}] =\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$$

which gives

$$\begin{array}{}
SD[\hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2] &=& \sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{n}} \\ 
&\approx& \sqrt{\frac{\hat p_1(1-\hat p_1)}{n} + \frac{\hat p_2(1-\hat p_2)}{n}} \\
&\approx& \sqrt{\frac{(89/98)(9/98)}{98} + \frac{(114/147)(33/147)}{147}}\\
&\approx & 0.045
\end{array}$$

So the difference $d$ is roughly 3 standard errors.

---

The numbers in the *samples* 89/98 and 114/147 are different and indicate that the populations from which they were sampled. But this does not *need* to mean that the populations from which were sampled are different. It can also have been the sampling that differed or made the difference appear unlikely large.

Also relevant is *how* the measurements are taken. Why are the numbers different and what do the ratios mean? Are the samples representative of the underlying populations? Was the sampling the same?

Comment: Hi @Sextus Empiricus, Thank you for your explanation, its appreciated. I'm comparing Amino acids counts of specific positions in 2 different data sets, the first collected before 2000 and the second collected in 2010-2012. i'm trying to see if there is an increase in the percentage of Amino acid after 10 years, but i'm not sure if this comparison is correct because i have different number in the 2 groups. can you please help me to understand this ?

Comment: If the data you have (or can get) is counts, it is up to you to decide whether higher counts of this kind really mean more amino acids. If you doubt that it's valid to use counts in this way, you might consider whether there is a valid amino acid assay for experimental units. Then you might use a t test for normally distributed assays, otherwise a nonpraametric two sample Wilcoxon signed rank test.

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi the computation that I gave in the answer is like the situation where you roll a dice 98 times and another dice 147 times and count the fraction of sixes for each dice. Which should be around 0.167 and in terms of counts respectively around 16/98 and 25/147. Due to variations you might observe 9/98 and 33/147, but it is not likely...

Comment: ... for dice rolls as a model, this is straightforward. But what I do not know is how you performed your measurements and how you achieve these figures. I assumed that they are like counts of independent random events as in the dice rolls, but maybe there is something else going on? What sort of distribution, does the data follow? E.g. if you are having some assay in which the same amino acid might get counted twice by accident, then it is not a binomial distribution anymore.